# Chrome on Android delays Websocket traffic

Tags: android, google-chrome, websocket

I'm developing a turn-based game using web technologies. The game communicates with a server using plain websocket. I've found a strange issue that Chrome on Android sometimes delays a reception of messages from server up to 10 seconds even if a device is connected via WiFi! Curiously a Chrome browser running the same application on a desktop PC connected to the same network receives websocket messages immediately. Every message is about 100-150b length and the traffic range is about 1..30 messages/minute.

It seems that Android or Chrome tries to "optimize" traffic usage or CPU consumption and accumulates short messages in a buffer before doing Websocket.onmessage() call. There are no delays at network level: the connection is stable, server socket has enabled TCP_NODELAY, desktop browsers work as expected. The same behavior was reproduced on varios devices: Huawei, Samsung Galaxy, Xiaomi Redmi, etc...

Has anyone more experienced with this problem? Are there any additional configuration for Websocket or Page that makes websocket connection more responsive on Android?

Chrome Desktop: 84.0.4147.89,
Chrome Android: 84.0.4147.105

Comment: I'm experiencing a very similar problem. In my case the delay only happens during a touch move. It doesn't happen if you hold your finger in one place. As soon as you stop moving your finger (even if you are still touching the screen) the accumulated events happen all at once. As far as I can tell, you can continue delaying the messages indefinitely by continuing the touch move. The only hint I can see is that when I use remote debugging the problem doesn't happen (but the performance becomes really crumby). Here's the site, in case it helps: http://www.cesoid.com/squirrel

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because I was using `requestIdleCallback` to schedule websocket writes. I switched it to `requestAnimationFrame` and the problem went away.